# How to add my code in reorder action using my custom module

Tags: reorder

I want to add my code in reorder action using my custom module.

I want to do this because I am  using this event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` to set custom option and price but when I reorder that order that time price and custom option is not set as last order.

Is that correct way to set that option and price ?

Comment: So to be clear, you want to change the product prices when the reorder action refills the quote with the old items?

Comment: yes i want to set product price and custom option with old items...

Comment: have you used magento default custom option or create new field or attribute?

Comment: @Abdul i m using magento default custom option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference-https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570013/4572021

in `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event

```
action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
    if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_reorder')
    {
        $buyInfo = $obs->getQuoteItem()->getBuyRequest();
        if ($option= $buyInfo->getCustomOption())
        {
            //get my custom option using that i can get price and set a price

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can remember to reorder Magento actually merges the quote. So using `sales_quote_merge_before` would be an event you could watch.

Another option would be to use the `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` event. It's triggered before calculating totals like subtotal and grand total.

However, for both options you don't know if it is a normal order or a reorder so you might want to store in a session or something a reorder has been triggered